# WPF UI not updating and not sure why?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, task

I had a timer in my app that was causing too many thread locks so I decided to replace the timer with a task that runs in a loop.  Now, when using the task my UI properties are not updating correctly.  I figured it was a thread issue so I move the UI updates outside of the task and used await, but the UI still isn't working.  In debug I following the code to the UI and it's on the main thread with the correct data but the UI never updates.  The symptom is a frozen UI and a process memory that just keep growing.  I"m lost on how to fix this one.  Maybe someone can help?

```
 private static void OnStaticPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    { StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new propertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

 private void PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
       {
           switch (e.PropertyName)
            {
                case "SiderealTime":
                    TextLst.Content = _util.HoursToHMS(TelescopeHardware.SiderealTime);
                    break;
                case "RightAscension":
                    TextRa.Content = _util.HoursToHMS(TelescopeHardware.RightAscension, "h ", "m ", "s", 3);
                    break;
       }));
    }

 private static async void Main_Mount_Loop()
    {            
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var ct = _cts.Token;
        var keepGoing = true;
        while (keepGoing)
        {
            var task = Task.Run(() => 
            {
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                Task.Delay(1000, ct);
                MoveAxes();
                if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                       {
                           // Clean up here, then...
                           keepGoing = false;
                       }
            }, ct);
            await task;
            UpdateUi();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Task.Delay` returns a Task which should be `await`ed. but it is not and there is no delay. remove outer task `var task = Task.Run`, and await Task.Delay. there should be some improvement

Comment: ah, I see how that works now, thanks!

Comment: Why are you using a cancellation token source that never cancels the cancellation token.

Answer (score 0):

[Reactive extensions](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) seem to be a more suited library for this usage:

```
Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
    .Do(_ => MoveAxes())
    .SubscribeOn(DispatcherScheduler.Current)
    .Subscribe(_ => UpdateUi());
```